# How to count frequency of elements in a bigquery array field

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I am looking for a table that gives a frequency count of the elements in the fields `l_0, l_1, l_2, l_3`.

For example the output should look like this:

```
| author_id  | year | l_o.name         | l_0.count| l1.name    | l1.count | l2.name             | l2.count| l3.name            | l3.count|
| 2164089123 | 1987 | biology          | 3        | botany     | 3        |                     |         |                    |         |
| 2595831531 | 1987 | computer science | 2        | simulation | 2        | computer simulation | 2       | mathematical model | 2       |
```

---

**Edit:**

In some cases the array field might have more than one type of element. For example `l_0` could be  `['biology', 'biology', 'geometry', 'geometry']`. In that case the output for fields `l_0, l_1, l_2, l_3` would be a nested repeated field with all the elements in `l_0.name` and all the corresponding counts in the `l_0.count`.

Comment: it is still not clear what exactly the content of the each repeated field! is it always the same element per field or it can be multiple? and if multiple - how result should look like?

Comment: It is not always the same element per field. For multiple elements the count of the objects should be a repeated nested object with element name and the element count.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work, assuming you want to count on a per-array basis:

```
SELECT
  author_id,
  year,
  (SELECT AS STRUCT ANY_VALUE(l_0) AS name, COUNT(*) AS count
   FROM UNNEST(l_0) AS l_0) AS l_0,
  (SELECT AS STRUCT ANY_VALUE(l_1) AS name, COUNT(*) AS count
   FROM UNNEST(l_1) AS l_1) AS l_1,
  (SELECT AS STRUCT ANY_VALUE(l_2) AS name, COUNT(*) AS count
   FROM UNNEST(l_2) AS l_2) AS l_2,
  (SELECT AS STRUCT ANY_VALUE(l_3) AS name, COUNT(*) AS count
   FROM UNNEST(l_3) AS l_3) AS l_3
FROM YourTable;
```

To avoid so much repetition, you can make use of a SQL UDF:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetNameAndCount(elements ARRAY<STRING>) AS (
  (SELECT AS STRUCT ANY_VALUE(elem) AS name, COUNT(*) AS count
   FROM UNNEST(elements) AS elem)
);

SELECT
  author_id,
  year,
  GetNameAndCount(l_0) AS l_0,
  GetNameAndCount(l_1) AS l_1,
  GetNameAndCount(l_2) AS l_2,
  GetNameAndCount(l_3) AS l_3
FROM YourTable;
```

If you potentially need to account for multiple different names within an array, you can have the UDF return an array of them with associated counts instead:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetNamesAndCounts(elements ARRAY<STRING>) AS (
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT elem AS name, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM UNNEST(elements) AS elem
    GROUP BY elem
    ORDER BY count
  )
);

SELECT
  author_id,
  year,
  GetNamesAndCounts(l_0) AS l_0,
  GetNamesAndCounts(l_1) AS l_1,
  GetNamesAndCounts(l_2) AS l_2,
  GetNamesAndCounts(l_3) AS l_3
FROM YourTable;
```

Note that if you want to perform counting across rows, however, you'll need to unnest the arrays and perform the `GROUP BY` at the outer level, but it doesn't look like this is your intention based on the question.

Comment: The actual solution I was looking for is perfectly done by the last solution you provided. I clarified my question in a later edit too. Thanks a lot!