# Standard SQL - How to count frequency of values in array

Tags: sql, arrays, count, google-bigquery

I get the following Table with the query underneath:

[image: result of SQL query - screenshot]

```
SELECT 
  fullVisitorId,
  COUNT(fullVisitorId) as id_count,
  ARRAY_AGG(trafficSource.medium) AS trafic_medium
FROM 
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170101`
GROUP BY
  fullVisitorId
ORDER BY
  id_count DESC
```

For each of the values in the `trafic_medium` column (e.g.: cpc, referral, organic, etc.) I am trying to figure out how often each value occurred in the array, so preferably add a new column 'count' that shows ho often that value occurred?

```
+-----------+---------+------+
| array_agg | medium  | count|
+-----------+---------+------+
| 123       | cpc     |   2  |
+-----------+---------+------+
|           | organic |   1  |
+-----------+---------+------+
|           | cpc     |   2  |
+-----------+---------+------+
| 456       | organic |   2  |
+-----------+---------+------+
|           | organic |   2  |
+-----------+---------+------+
|           | cpc     |   1  |
+-----------+---------+------+
```

I'm new to SQL so I'm quite stuck.

I tried this so far:

```
WITH medium AS
(
    SELECT 
        fullVisitorId,
        COUNT(fullVisitorId) as id_count,
        ARRAY_AGG(trafficSource.medium) AS trafic_medium
    FROM 
        `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170101`
    GROUP BY
        fullVisitorId
    ORDER BY
        id_count DESC
) 
SELECT
    fullVisitorId,
    trafic_medium,
    (SELECT AS STRUCT Any_Value(trafic_medium) AS name, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM 
    UNNEST(trafic_medium) AS trafic_medium) AS trafic_medium_2,
FROM 
    medium
```

Based on this thread:
[How to count frequency of elements in a bigquery array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48411331/how-to-count-frequency-of-elements-in-a-bigquery-array-field)

However this only shows the number of 'Any_Value not for all distinct.

I would appreciate some help!

p.s. I am doing this in BigQuery on the 'bigquery-public-dataset.google_analytics_sample'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL to help you get started

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, trafic_medium,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT medium, COUNT(1) `count`
    FROM t.trafic_medium medium
    GROUP BY medium
  ) stats
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

if to apply to sample/dummy data from you question  as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 123 id, ['cpc', 'organic', 'cpc'] trafic_medium UNION ALL
  SELECT 456, ['organic', 'organic', 'cpc']
)
SELECT id, trafic_medium,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT medium, COUNT(1) `count`
    FROM t.trafic_medium medium
    GROUP BY medium
  ) stats
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
-- ORDER BY id
```

result will be

[image]

As an option - you can use below version

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT medium, `count`
    FROM t.trafic_medium medium
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT AS STRUCT medium, COUNT(1) `count`
      FROM t.trafic_medium medium
      GROUP BY medium
    ) stats
    USING(medium) 
  ) trafic_medium  
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
-- ORDER BY id
```

which (if to apply to the same dummy data) will output below

[image]

This version looks more aligned with your expected result

Comment: thank you very much, worked out perfectly! What does the COUNT(1) in this case do?

Comment: actually your first version was exactly what i was looking for in the 'end solution' but the new one does fit the question better!

Comment: yea, i felt this way - but was not sure. as of `count(1)` - count() along with group by counts how many times item is in given set of items (in this case - within the array)